# Tiny font in Eclipse

Tags: lenovo, fonts, eclipse

I'm working with Eclipse Neon 3, Ubuntu 17.04, on a Lenovo ideapad Y700.

Some of the texts in Eclipse are extremely small which makes them unreadable. See [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53OB4.png).

Every other font in Ubuntu looks right. I've found some posts mentioning small icons in Eclipse with hidpi, but for me it's not only the icons but the texts, and it's not even all of them, just some.

Anyone has a clue how to fix this?